# array conversion of date time into string

Tags: python, mysql, string, date

I have an array like this

`A =['datetime.datetime("2015", " 9", " 18", " 8", " 1", " 19")']`

while selecting query from database. I want to convert the array to a string like

`datetime.datetime("2015-09-18-08-01-19")`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is your question? You should edit your post to make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Do you really want `"datetime.datetime(2015-09-18-08-01-19)"` or  `datetime.datetime("2015-09-18-08-01-19")` ?

Comment: what is the source of that data? It is not even a valid `repr(datetime_object)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, May be it may help you

```
A[0].replace(",", "-").replace("\"-", "-").replace('" ', "").replace(" ", "")
```

will give you.

```
'datetime.datetime("2015-9-18-8-1-19")'
```

Comment: Not OP's output. You miss the `0`'s

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> import datetime
>>> A =[' datetime.datetime("2015", " 9", " 18", " 8", " 1", " 19")']
>>> d = "-".join((re.findall("\s*(\d+)\s*", A[0])))
>>> d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
>>> res = 'datetime.datetime("{0}")'.format(d1)
>>> print res
datetime.datetime("2015-09-18-08-01-19")
```